# Getting error when exporting ipa in development method

Tags: python, ios, xcode, export, ipa

When I select IPA distribution method as development and try to export,  I am getting this same error for all my projects, and I am not using python anywhere so why I am getting this error. Please help me to solve this error.

I am using Xcode 9.2

```
ipatool failed with an exception:#<RuntimeError: Couldn't locate python in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin>
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:157:in `locate_tool'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:137:in `unicode_equal?'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1703:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1703:in `each'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1703:in `detect'
```

[image: Xcode export error, when exporting for development]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks to Alper to guiding me in the right direction, when we create or export an IPA Xcode needs **python** which is located in **/usr/bin/python** path, and in my case I have installed **python** but it was not on that location, so I search for python executable file in my system and copy paste that executable file on this **/usr/bin/** location, and it work's.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that Apple use python and that something has broken. Since the error is in your `Xcode.app` path, I'd recommend a reinstall of your Xcode to see whether that fixes things.

Comment: Thanks, I am uninstalling Xcode and then I will Install it again

Comment: nothing change, still getting the same error after reinstall Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Did you maybe mess around with your system Python? Check whether you still have Python (`which python`). You could try installing an alternative Python via homebrew, like it says here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/#doing-it-right
You could also upgrade to Xcode 9.3 like everybody else.

Comment: I uninstall python and reinstall it, still getting that same error while exporting IPA.

Comment: You can't really uninstall python on an OS X system.

Comment: I got the cause of this error, thankyou to guide me in right direction, actually in my system python is missing on this /usr/bin/python location and Xcode is finding that file in /usr/bin/ dir, so I manually added it, and it works!!!.

Comment: Unbelievable! I'm glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because XCode can't find path to python binary file.

**1) Find your python binary file:**

Enter in your terminal:

```
python
```

Next enter:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

The screen will display the paths to various python directories.
Example:

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Copy path to bin/ folder and exit from python:

Just press *command+d*

**2) Copy python binary file to /usr/bin destination:**
Enter in your terminal:

```
cp {INSERT HERE COPIED PATH TO /bin PYTHON DIRECTORY}/python /usr/bin/
```

Example:

```
cp /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/
```

**After that the issue will fixed!**

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have problem with application not locating your python - symlink will do the trick.
For some reason my pythons are installed in `/usr/local/bin`, while one of my IDEs searches in `/usr/bin`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

fixed this issue.
enjoy!